# Developer tool shows CSS I can't locate in order to edit

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, developer-tools

This is probably a newb problem that's very easy to fix.

[Here is my site](http://blergh.us)

I'm trying to change the background color of the menu wrap: The box around the words INFO.

Using Chromes Developer tools I was able to find that the Background color is coming from CSS line 43

This is my problem

```
body #menu_wrap, #topmenu ul li ul li{ background:#302F2F url("http://blergh.us/wp-content/themes/theron-lite/images/transblack.png") repeat!important;}
```

The CSS rule however is not there when I try to edit. Instead I find this garbage:

```
#menu_wrap{width:1000px; float:left; background:#7d928f url(images/menu_wrap.png) repeat;}
#topmenu{text-align:center;}
.menu-header{margin:auto; padding:0; display:block;}
#topmenu ul{ margin:0; padding:0;}
#topmenu ul li{list-style-type:none; display:inline-block; position:relative; margin-top:0px;padding:25px 15px;}
#topmenu li a{ font-size:18px; color:#fff;}
#topmenu ul > li:hover{  background:#7d928f url(images/transblack.png) repeat;}
#menu-icon{display:none;}
```

Where is my CSS hiding?

Answer (score 0):

If you use google chrom right click inspect element. On the css panel Matched CSS rules it shows blergh.us which is your home page.

This means

```
body #menu_wrap, #topmenu ul li ul li{ background:#302F2F url("http://blergh.us/wp-content/themes/theron-lite/images/transblack.png") repeat!important;}
```

Is on the page.

Just right click on your home. Look at the last style tag right above 
   `</head>`

You will find your style

```
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #ffffff; background-image:   url('http://blergh.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/DAMASK.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat; background-position: top center; background-attachment: scroll; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're setting the background of the list item which is overriding the background

```
body #menu_wrap, #topmenu ul li ul li{ background:#302F2F url("http://blergh.us/wp-content/themes/theron-lite/images/transblack.png") repeat!important;}
```

change it to this

```
#topmenu ul li ul li{ background:#302F2F url("http://blergh.us/wp-content/themes/theron-lite/images/transblack.png") repeat!important;}
```

Comment: That makes sense. My problem is that I can't find that CSS rule anywhere in my stylesheet in order to change it. It's hiding. 

A search for "302F2F" in my CSS doesn't turn anything up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `Theme Functions (functions.php)`.

```
body #menu_wrap, #topmenu ul li ul li{ background:#302f2f url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/transblack.png") repeat!important;}
```

Change here `#302f2f` with your color.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are correct, however they don't really answer your question. The CSS is to be found on the client-side HTML, that's correct. But how do you edit it?

I am assuming you are running a Wordpress site (can't access the link you posted, but from the CSS you posted it is clear). Wordpress allows plug-ins to run server-side. These plug-ins can dynamically add CSS to any given page. It is likely that the CSS in your qquestion is injected by a plug-in.

To figure out which plug-in is generating that CSS, you can try disabling each plug-in one at a time. When you see the CSS isn't imported anymore, you have found the guilty one.